# Check if row exists before updating a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in database with:

```
Time      Name
11:23     Tom
12:22     Jack
```

And a .txt file

```
12:22, Anna
```

This is my code

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

// open txt file
$fp = fopen($filename,"r");

//parse the csv file row by row
while(($row = fgetcsv($fp,"500",",")) != FALSE)
{
    //insert csv data into mysql table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO project-1 (time, name) VALUES('" . implode("','",$row) . "')";
    if(!mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}

fclose($fp);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
```

I want to stop import .txt file to database if time value in database = time value in .txt

Comment: Sounds like a great project! Let us know if you have a question!

Comment: So show us the code you are using to do this insert into the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edited and showed my code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly or not but this is what I suggest you to do. If you had another issue please tell my I'm gonna help you.

```
$conn=mysqli_connect('host','username','password','dbname');

$file=fopen('a.txt','r');
if($file){
    while(($line=fgets($file))!==null){
        //read every line in txt and but before inserting into db check the time like this:
        //first parse the time out of the line:
        $time_array=explode(',',$line);
        //now you have an array with to indexes. 0=time, 1=name.
        $query="SELECT * FROM table WHERE time='$time_array[0]'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
            //code for inserting into db;
        }else{
            //stop inserting code and do fclose() or anything else.
        }
    }
}
```